# Adding a node programmatically

Tags: php, drupal

I am very new to Drupal. I need to develop a site using this CMS. I can understand creating content as an admin. But I would like to create content from code. For example I want to create articles in the backend programmatically without publishing them. So that site admin can review and publish them if he wants to. Tasks like these.Are there any references for programmers? About the structure of drupal code and where to write what things like that. Not videos I can't watch them in office.

Comment: This question belongs in [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/?as=1) :).

Comment: Yes there's a whole page of examples in the first page of Google results for "Adding a node programatically" funnily enough. You don't even need to put "Drupal" in the search. Please don't ask this on Drupal Answers, it has been asked and answered many, many times (as it has here)

Comment: yeah there are so many results in google...but all results show a function in which a node object is created...but doesn't give any specifics as to where the code is to be stored and how that function is called. It is very difficult for beginners to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom code in Drupal is generally done with the help of modules.

One way to familiarize yourself with the Drupal API could be to install the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

In your Google searches, go for tutorials about writing your own modules.

THis being said, saving a node programmatically is fairly straightforward & I doubt you will have problems finding out how to do it.

Your main problem is to understand the "Drupal Way".

You can check excellent resources such as
- [buildamodule.com](http://buildamodule.com/)
- [drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me/)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION !**

You can use below code to create a node programatically with drupal,

```
    $node = new stdClass(); // Create a new node object
    $node->type = 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE';
    node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->status = 0; // un-published
    $node->uid = 'USER_ID';
    $node->title = 'YOUR_TITLE';
    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION';
    $node->body['und'][0]['summary'] = 'YOUR_SHORT_DESCRIPTION';
    $node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';
    $node = node_submit($node); //prepare node for saving
    node_save($node); // save node
```